# Why does this thread never complete itself?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a simple Runnable class that is supposed to iterate through two dimensions of world data, and perform a function at each point.  I also have a boolean value and a return method that will tell when the thread is done.

```
public class Generator implements Runnable
{

private World world;
private Random seed;

private boolean genComplete = false;

public Generator(World world)
{
    // Implementation
}

public boolean isComplete()
{
    return genComplete;
}

/**
 * Begins world generator thread.
 */
@Override
public void run()
{
    world.initializeWorldTileData();

    generateWholeWorld();

    System.out.println("Completed");
    genComplete = true;
}

/**
 * Processes entire world generation tree.
 */
private void generateWholeWorld()
{
    world.saveData();

    for (int x = 0; x < world.getWorldSizeX(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < world.getWorldSizeY(); y++)
        {
            // Example function.
            x();
        }
    }
}

private void x()
{
    // When nothing is performed genComplete equals true.
}
}
```

Under this example, when run the `generateWholeWorld()` method is executed fully and `Completed` is printed.  However, if I add any function into `x()`:

```
private void x()
{
       System.out.println("Example function");
}
```

The thread keeps running infinitely (runs through the for loops endlessly), even though it should be able to perform the task in a couple seconds.  `genComplete` never equals true.

Edit: The thread is being created and observed from a GUI loading screen that changes when `genComplete` is true.

```
private Thread generator;
private boolean doneGenerating;

public ScreenGenerateWorld(Screen parent, InitialWorldSettings settings)
{
    super(parent);
    world = World.createNewWorld(settings);
    this.generator = new Thread(world.getWorldGenerator());
    generator.start();
}

@Override
public void update()
{       
    doneGenerating = world.getWorldGenerator().isComplete();

    if (doneGenerating)
    {
        info.setText("Press \"A\" to Continue...");

        if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_A))
            AntFarm.getAntFarm().changeActiveScreen(new ScreenWorld(parent, world));
    }

    // Render code
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show more of the classes involved including how you spawn and start your thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mutable state kills in multi-threaded Java apps.  I strongly recommend that you put some synchronization around that genComplete state variable so that all threads have a common view of its value.

```
public class Generator implements Runnable 
{
    ...
    private boolean genComplete = false;

    public synchronized void setComplete() {
        getComplete = true;
    }

    public synchronized isComplete() {
        return genComplete;
    }
    ...
    /**
     * Begins world generator thread.
    */
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        world.initializeWorldTileData();
        generateWholeWorld();
        System.out.println("Completed");
        setComplete();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: +1. Or make it an AtomicBoolean, or make it volatile.

Comment: volatile probably does work better.  I've always hated synchronization as it feels like I'm "publishing" or exposing something that should be internal to my object.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with comment about the immutability, it's always preferred to use immutable objects,
but i think that synchronized wouldn't be the best solution,

You might be better off using the "Executors" instead of the threads.
you can read about it in the next short tutorial in Jenkov's blog: [Jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)

And you'll want to pass to the "call" function an implementation that implements the interface [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) that returns a "Future" object that you can ask if the task is completed.

You can use the "get" blocking function that will wait for the processes to finish.

I hope i got your need correctly and that the answer will help you.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's only a hypothesis, but it seems like you get a spin-lock with update() method, which is optimized by JVM after several iterations so that genComplete is cached and spinlocking thread never determines genComplete's value changed. When your method x() is empty method run() finishs fast and JVM havent optimize your code yet (by default Oracle HotSpot JIT turns on optimizatons after 1500 method calls in client mode), but I/O operations are 1) blocking (which means more CPU time for other threads) 2) not very fast, so optimizations gets involved when x() contains System.out.println(). The volatile will fix issue in ths case.

I'd better recommend you to use Executors and callbacks. For instance:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        button.setEnabled(false); 
        label.setText("busy"); 
        backgroundExec.execute(new Runnable() { 
            public void run() { 
                try { 
                    doBigComputation(); 
                } 
                finally { 
                    GuiExecutor.instance().execute(new Runnable() { 
                        public void run() { 
                            button.setEnabled(true); 
                            label.setText("idle"); 
                        } 
                    }); 
                } 
            }
        }); 
    } 
});
```

More on that you can learn from Java Concurrency in Practice.